# Date Range Search Datatable using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I need to search data from a specific date range . Here's what I did

Here's my
**MODEL**

```
public function rangeDate($start_date, $end_date){

    $query = $this->db->select($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.id,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_type,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_cno,'.$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.id as custid,'.$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.cust_name,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_price, '.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_tax,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.pay_due, SUM('.$this->tables['invent_sales'].'.paid_amnt) as payment,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp')
        ->join($this->tables['invent_cust'], $this->tables['invent_inv'].'.cust_id='.$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.id','LEFT')
        ->join($this->tables['invent_sales'], $this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_cno='.$this->tables['invent_sales'].'.inv_cno','LEFT')
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.status !=', 1)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.status !=', 0)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp >=', $start_date)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp <=', $end_date)
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_sales'].".inv_cno")
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_inv'].".inv_cno")
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_inv'].".timestamp")
        ->get($this->tables['invent_inv']);

    return $query;
}
```

Here's my
**CONTROLLER**

```
public function rangeDates(){
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

    $return = $this->ion_auth->rangeDate($start_date,$end_date);

    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

here's the ajax
**JS**

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
todayBtn: 'linked',
format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
autoclose: true
});

function fetch_data(start_date='', end_date=''){
var dataTable = $('#table-sales').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order":[],
    "ajax":{
        url: "sales/rangeDates",
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#table-sales').html(data);
        }
    }
});
}

$('#search').click(function(){

var inv_type = $('#invType').val();
var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
var end_date = $('#end_date').val();

if(start_date != '' && end_date != '' && inv_type != 0){
    $('#table-sales').DataTable().destroy();
    fetch_data(start_date,end_date);
}else{
    alert('Both Date is Required and Choose what to show!');
}

});
```

Now my problem is that on my screen when i click the search button on my view it pops up a processing dialog box and there's no error on the console . So i tried looking at the network and here's what I found.

[image]

They are all null and I don't know why. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong on this stuff. Thank you in advance .

MORE INFO: And here is my

**VIEW**

```html
<div class="box-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                  
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-daterange">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group start-date">
                        <label>From</label>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                          <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                          </div>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="start_date" name="start_date">
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.input group -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group end-date">
                        <label>To</label>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                          <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                          </div>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="end_date" name="end_date">
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.input group -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <label>Select</label>
                      <select class="form-control select2" id="invType" name="invType" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option value="0" />Select</option>
                        <option value="1">Department Store</option>
                        <option value="2">Local</option>
                        <option value="3">Provincial</option>
                        <option value="4">UNITOP</option>
                        <option value="5">GAISANO</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Go </label>
                          <div class="input-group date">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-md btn-search" name = "search" id="search">Search!</button> 
                          </div>
                          <!-- /.input group -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                <table id="table-sales" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>DR</th>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Customer</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                      <th>Paid Amnt</th>
                      <th>Balance</th>
                      <th>Receipt</th>
                      <th>Remarks</th>
                      <th>Items</th>
                      <th style="width:55px;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($sales_inv as $inv) {
                        $balance = $inv->inv_price-$inv->payment;
                        $status = "";
                        $payment = $inv->payment;
                        
                        if ($inv->inv_type==1) {
                          $status = "Department Store";
                        }elseif($inv->inv_type==2){
                          $status = "Local";
                        }elseif($inv->inv_type==3){
                          $status = "Provincial";
                        }elseif($inv->inv_type==4){
                          $status = "UNITOP";
                        }elseif($inv->inv_type==5){
                          $status = "GAISANO";
                        }
                    ?>
                      <tr class="row-<?php echo $inv->id; ?>">
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn-inv-show" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>@<?php echo $inv->id; ?>"><?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($inv->timestamp)); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $inv->cust_name; ?></td>
                        <td class="price-<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">Php <?php echo number_format($inv->inv_price,2); ?></td>
                        <td class="payment-<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">Php <?php echo number_format($payment,2); ?></td>
                        <td class="bal-<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">Php <?php echo number_format($balance,2); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $status; ?></td>
                        <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-rem" data-value="<?php echo $inv->id; ?>">View Remarks
                          </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-item" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>">View Item
                          </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-print" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>
                          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-add-pay" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>@<?php echo $inv->custid; ?>@<?php echo $inv->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></button>
                          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-edit-pay" data-value="<?php echo $inv->inv_cno; ?>@<?php echo $inv->custid; ?>@<?php echo $inv->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
                  <tfooter>
                    <tr>
                      <th>DR</th>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Customer</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                      <th>Paid Amnt</th>
                      <th>Balance</th>
                      <th>Receipt</th>
                      <th>Remarks</th>
                      <th style="width:55px;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfooter>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!-- /.table-responsive -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </section>
        <!-- right col -->
      </div>
```

## TIMESTRAMP FORMAT

[image]

## PROCESSING IMAGE

[image]

Comment: show the timestamp format of your database.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi edited my question sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [generate some "results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)" from the `$query`. At the end of the model replace

```
return $query;
```

with

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: When I did this i have `No properties` on the Network Console on Dev Tool

Comment: then your query returned no rows of data

Comment: I'm new to this sir . What should I do?

Comment: You need to debug the output of the model. Start by figuring out how to use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and/or [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Build the query one piece at a time. Making sure you get expected results at each step. As a general rule: Write code in small steps, testing each step along the way.

Comment: Yes, you can. While debugging you may want to use `exit` to stop script execution from moving past the point you are checking. For instance, in the model try `var_dump($query->result_array()); exit;` to see what data the query returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183793/discussion-between-dfriend-and-boonmingprog).

Comment: it gives me array(size = 0) empty

Comment: are you still there sir?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a somewhat similar problem while fetching data from the database base on date range. I have solved the problem by adding the `00:00:00` to start date and `23:59:59` to the end date. By adding the `23:59:59` to end date implies that it will actually fetch the data with last date and time. Check if this solves your problem.
Do this in your model

```
public function rangeDate($start_date, $end_date){
    $start_date = $start_date .' 00:00:00';
    $end_date = $end_date . ' 23:59:59';

    $query = $this->db->select($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.id,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_type,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_cno,'.$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.id as custid,'.$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.cust_name,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_price, '.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_tax,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.pay_due, SUM('.$this->tables['invent_sales'].'.paid_amnt) as payment,'.$this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp')
        ->join($this->tables['invent_cust'], $this->tables['invent_inv'].'.cust_id='.$this->tables['invent_cust'].'.id','LEFT')
        ->join($this->tables['invent_sales'], $this->tables['invent_inv'].'.inv_cno='.$this->tables['invent_sales'].'.inv_cno','LEFT')
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.status !=', 1)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.status !=', 0)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp >=', $start_date)
        ->where($this->tables['invent_inv'].'.timestamp <=', $end_date)
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_sales'].".inv_cno")
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_inv'].".inv_cno")
        ->group_by($this->tables['invent_inv'].".timestamp")
        ->get($this->tables['invent_inv']);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Be more clear sir . Where should I add the `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` on JS or on my model?

Comment: Still no result sir . It is always `Processing`

Comment: what do you mean by "It is always processing"